# What is the effect of dereferencing a string literal in C?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%c",*"abcde");
    return 0;
}
```

how 'a' will be the output for this program? 
let me know why the output is 'a' when compiled in turbo c..and what does '*' here imply?

Comment: Read more about pointers and especially _pointer dereferencing_.

Comment: It would be best to end the printed data with a newline: `printf("%c\n", *"abcde");`.

Answer (score 2):

`"abcde"` is a string literal, which is an array of characters (`char[]`). It is *typically* placed in a read-only data section of the program. If you were to pass that to `printf`, the compiler is actually passing the address of that array to `printf`.

However, here you are *de-referencing* that pointer, which passes just the first character.

Here is an equivalent, more verbose version that may make more sense:

```
const char* str = "abcde";    // str is a char* pointer to "abcde"
char c = *str;                // De-reference that pointer - in other words,
                              //   get me the char that it points to.
printf("%c", c);              // Pass that char to printf, where %c is
                              //   expecting a char.
```

Comment: C says nothing of literals being stored in readonly memory, only that modifying a string literal results in UB.

Comment: Yes, and couldn't it do the same for the OP's example? The result is equally as deterministic.

Comment: This answer contains a lot of irrelevant factoids and misses the only important fact: that arrays decay to pointers in most contexts, including this one.

Comment: The OP clearly has little understanding of how pointers work - sorry for trying to provide a little insight via example. Please, provide an answer so we can critique as well.

Comment: That's exactly why I think it's important to address this and not gloss over it.

Answer (score 2):

`"abcde"` is a string literal and thus has array type. In any context but `sizeof` or the operand of `&`, an array decays to a pointer to its first element. Thus, when used as the operand of the unary `*` operator, `"abcde"` is evaluated to a pointer to the "a" at the beginning of the string, and the `*` operator dereferences that pointer, obtaining the value `'a'`. Passing this value (an integer) to `printf` for formatting with the `%c` format specifier causes `printf` to print the corresponding character, "a", to stdout.

Comment: +1 For a concise answer that has all the elements the OP needs to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the printf function takes in a const char* as a parameter, and as said above a string is just an array of char values. When passing an array in c++ the compiler takes it as a pointer to the first element of the [].

Ex.
string nums[] = {"one", "two);
string* p2 = nums; //Totally valid and how the compiler would sees this would be an address to "one".

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's question about what the `*` does in their second argument to `printf`.