# what happens when you dereference a string in c++

Tags: c++

Why does the following code produce the output "h"? I do not understand it. Since it's dereferencing it, shouldn't it print out its memory address?

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << *("hello");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dereferencing generally does the opposite of getting an address.

Comment: A string literal is interpreted as a character array. Derefencing an array returns the first value.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898535/what-is-the-effect-of-dereferencing-a-string-literal-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is saved at some memory location in the binary (when the source is compiled).

A string like `"hello"` is converted to a `char *` (pointer to char). Therefore when you dereference it, it will get you the first char of your "string".

Comment: @stoicbutterfly No.  They are arrays of characters.

Comment: then why is it converted to char *?

Comment: @stoicbutterfly A string _literal_ is an expression that yields a _value_ of type `const char *`.  The string literal is not the same thing as the string.  The literal is the bytes `"hello"` that appear in your source file,  The string is an array of characters `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` that appear in the executable, and whenever you use the "name" of an array as an expression, you get a pointer to its first member.  It works that way in C++ because that's how it worked in C because...40 years of historical reasons.

Comment: A `char *` is usually a pointer to the first character of a character array.  Many functions will traverse the array, incrementing the pointer, until a '\0' character is found.  The functions may access beyond the array if a '\0' is not found. This is one reason that `std::string` is preferred to character arrays.

Answer (score 6):

"hello" evaluates to a pointer to the first character of the string , dereferencing it evaluates to that character.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal (`"hello"` in this case) is a array of `const char` of size `N` where `N` is the number of characters plus a null terminator.  That array can decay to a pointer to the first element.  When you dereference that pointer you now have the first element of the array, which is a character.  That is why `h` is printed as you gave `cout` a character.